# Perform actions after actions performed?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I essentially have three sprites. I want to start by having them all fade out. Once that's complete, I want to perform other operations on them. Here is my code:

```
    //Fade the sprites out
    oneMissedOrbIndicator.runAction(SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.5))
    firstTwoMissedOrbsIndicator.runAction(SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.5))
    secondTwoMissedOrbsIndicator.runAction(SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.5))

    //Do this after all three sprites have been faded out
    switch numberOfCollectionOrbsNotCollected {
    case 0:
        break
    case 1:
        oneMissedOrbIndicator.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.5))
    case 2:
        firstTwoMissedOrbsIndicator.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.5))
        secondTwoMissedOrbsIndicator.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.5))
    default:
        print("Unreachable switch statement case reached3!\n")
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE)

    }
```

However SpriteKit doesn't wait for the fading out action to be completed before moving on to the next action, so essentially what I want to happen after happens simultaneously.

How can I perform the switch statement after all three sprites have been faded out?

I have tried the following:

1) Having a while statement after the fading code. The while loop keeps looping while "hasActions" is true for any of the sprites. This just froze my app.

2) Performing the switch statement in the "completion" closure of the last sprite I fade out. This performs identically as the code above - the switch statement happens simultaneously for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could check for the completion of the actions like this

```
var completed = false

let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.5)

 oneMissedOrbIndicator.runAction(fadeOut, completion: {self.completed = true})
    firstTwoMissedOrbsIndicator.runAction(fadeOut)
    secondTwoMissedOrbsIndicator.runAction(fadeOut)
```

since you're running the actions at the same time, you could check the completion of only one to change the value of the boolean. You could now place your switch statement inside of the update function to check if completed is true.

```
    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

if completed == true {

switch numberOfCollectionOrbsNotCollected {
    case 0:
        break
    case 1:
        oneMissedOrbIndicator.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.5))
    case 2:
        firstTwoMissedOrbsIndicator.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.5))
        secondTwoMissedOrbsIndicator.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.5))
    default:
        print("Unreachable switch statement case reached3!\n")
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a sequence of actions, something like this:

```
SKAction *fadeout1 = [SKAction…….];
SKAction *fadeout2 = [SKAction…….];

[node runAction:fadeout1];
[node runAction:fadeout2];

SKAction *fadeout3 = [SKAction…….];
SKAction *somethingElseAfterFadeout = [SKAction …….];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[fadeout3, somethingElseAfterFadeout]];
[node runAction: sequence];
```